# Reference a Variable while Using Another

Tags: string, batch-file

Wasn't really sure as to what the title should be but my problem is that when I run the following:

```
set "var=craftbukkit-1.6.4-R2.0"
set "search=craftbukkit"
set vnum=%var:%search%=%
echo %vnum%
```

It returns "search" but its supposed to return the version number.

If however I replace the variable with the actual string , it does work:

```
set "var=craftbukkit-1.6.4-R2.0"
set vnum=%var:craftbukkit=%
echo %vnum%
```

This returns "-1.6.4-R2.0"

How do I reference the variable %search%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Delayed Expansion:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=craftbukkit-1.6.4-R2.0"
set "search=craftbukkit"
set vnum=!var:%search%=!
echo %vnum%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CALL set vnum=%%var:*%search%=%%
```

should remove all characters up to and including (the contents of the variable `search`) from `var` and assign the result to `vnum`

Answer (score -4):

Just add a plus to your vnum

```
set vnum=%var:+%search%=%
```

Comment: That just returns `%var%`